# What is the origin story of Kaal Brahm in our scripture?

Tags: puranas

I came across the origin story of Kaal Brahm. He was supposedly banished from Satyalok (along with his wife Prakriti) by Kabir Dev. He is also considered the creator of our Brahmaand , our trilok and is the father of Shiva, Vishnu and Brahma. He is unmanifest and we humans pray to him via Prakriti and the three Gods.

How much of this claim is backed by our scriptures? Is there any mention of Kabir Dev (the ultimate God) in our scriptures as suggested by Jagat Guru Rampal ?

Can someone share me the origin story as mentioned in our upanishads or purans? Even shloka # and Khand # would be helpful.

Comment: It does answer the Kabir Dev part of the question. I am still interested in the origin story.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not found in our scriptures...it's mainly from 'Gyan Ganga' book by Kabirpanthis in which they hv taken Sanskrit refrences from scriptures but mistranslated them...